# Kendo UI command behavior

Tags: jquery, user-interface, kendo-ui, grid

I'm using Kendo UI grid and I have made a custom command to be used. 
The command duplicates the selected row and I attached a post request to it. 
When the command is given for the first time, I can see from pycharm that the event is captured and post request is made. A duplicated row is then added to my grid. 
My problem here is that the duplicated row has commands that do not work: when I try to click on "Edit" no even is captured and from that moment, all other buttons are completely useless.

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Hero Project</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" 
   href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" />

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/kendo.all.min.js"> 
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div id="grid"></div>
  <script>

    var listOfObjects = JSON.parse('{{ mydata.data | tojson | safe}}');

    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
       scrollable: true,
       height: 500,
      columns: [        
      ],
      dataSource: listOfObjects,
      editable: {
        createAt: "bottom"
      },
      toolbar: ["create"],
    });
    <!--end of grid-->


    <!--start: add-->
     $(".k-grid-Savenew").on("click", function (e) {
        var dataItem = 
        $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
        $.ajax({
            url:'/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {"Label":dataItem.Label,
                          "Sistema":dataItem.Sistema,
                          "Nome":dataItem.Nome,
                          "Sigla":dataItem.Sigla,
                          "Referenti":dataItem.Referenti,
                          "Issues":dataItem.Issues,
                          "Stima":dataItem.Stima,
                          "Stato":dataItem.Stato,
                          "AFinire":dataItem.AFinire,
                          "Flag": "savenew"}
        });
    });
    <!--end: add-->

    <!--start: edit-->
    $(".k-grid-edit").on("click", function (e) {
        var dataItem = 
       $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
        $.ajax({
            url:'/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {"Label":dataItem.Label,
                           "Sistema":dataItem.Sistema,
                           "Nome":dataItem.Nome,
                           "Sigla":dataItem.Sigla,
                           "Referenti":dataItem.Referenti,
                           "Issues":dataItem.Issues,
                           "Stima":dataItem.Stima,
                           "Stato":dataItem.Stato,
                           "AFinire":dataItem.AFinire,
                           "Flag": "edit"}
        });
    });
    <!--end:edit-->

    <!--start: delete-->
    $(".k-grid-delete").on("click", function (e) {
        var dataItem =  
    $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
        $.ajax({
            url:'/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {"Label":dataItem.Label,
                           "Flag": "delete"}
        });
    });
    <!--end: delete-->

    <!--start: Duplicate-->
     $(".k-grid-Duplicate").on("click", function (e) {
        var dataItem = 
    $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
        var newRow = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid');
        newRow.dataSource.add({"Label":dataItem.Label,
                           "Sistema":dataItem.Sistema,
                           "Nome":dataItem.Nome,
                           "Sigla":dataItem.Sigla,
                           "Referenti":dataItem.Referenti,
                           "Issues":dataItem.Issues,
                           "Stima":dataItem.Stima,
                           "Stato":dataItem.Stato,
                           "AFinire":dataItem.AFinire})

        $.ajax({
            url:'/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {"Label":dataItem.Label,
                           "Sistema":dataItem.Sistema,
                           "Nome":dataItem.Nome,
                           "Sigla":dataItem.Sigla,
                           "Referenti":dataItem.Referenti,
                           "Issues":dataItem.Issues,
                           "Stima":dataItem.Stima,
                           "Stato":dataItem.Stato,
                           "AFinire":dataItem.AFinire,
                           "Flag": "duplicate"},
            success: function(data){
               if(data.success == true){ // if true (1)
                  setTimeout(function(){// wait for 5 secs(2)
                       location.reload(); // then reload the page.(3)
                  }, 5000);
                }
            }
        });

        $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').refresh();
      });
    <!--end: duplicate-->

     <!--start: add_from_toolbar-->
    $(".k-grid-add").on("click", function (e) {
        var dataItem = 
    $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
        $.ajax({
            url:'/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {"Flag": "add"}
        });
    });
    <!--end:add_from_toolbar-->
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Am I missing something? I was expecting my code to duplicate row and have commands/buttons working.

I also noticed that "Add new record" button seems to kill all other command buttons. It seems like it is waiting to be closed somehow but I can't figure out how to close it.

Comment: Did you check to see if an exception is thrown?

Comment: I was watching both pycharm and console but there is no exception. Adding a row stops all commands: both custom and kendo originals.

Comment: Can you provide a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) that we can play around?